# Does getMeasuredHeight() and getMeasuredWidth() work on nested views, and when do I use it?

Tags: android

I've been trying to measure the pixel dimensions of a view within a RelativeLayout that's within another RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    >
    ...
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/labels_placeholder"
    android:id="@+id/player_section_layout"
    >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/player_section_background"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100">
        <!--The view above is what I'm trying to measure-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/player_section_background_left"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:background="#AAAAAA"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/player_section_background_right"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:background="#DD0000"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/player_section"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/player_section_background">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/waveform_placeholder"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                />

        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried calling getMeasuredHeight() and getMeasuredWidth() right after referring to it in onCreateView() of the fragment:

```
waveformBackground = (LinearLayout)result.findViewById(R.id.player_section_background);
    waveformBackground.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("bckg_layout_dims", waveformBackground.getMeasuredWidth()+" "+waveformBackground.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    });
```

And it returns 0 for both.

I did hear something about it not working before the view is being drawn, but I don't know when exactly it finishes drawing. Is it after `OnCreateView`, and if so, can I call it in `OnActivityResult`?

Comment: did you try using `onResume`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is because the view is being drawn after you ask for the height and width. I used a ViewTreeObserver which constantly listens for changes in the views, and can access the measurements after the views has been drawn. Im not sure this is the best solution for your problem but you should look into it. Here's an example:

```
     mTitleContainer.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        int toolBarHeight = mTitle.getHeight() + mSubtitle.getHeight() + (int) TOOLBARPADDING;

                        if (toolBarHeight != mLastTitleHeight) {
                            CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams) mTitleToolbar.getLayoutParams();
                            layoutParams.height = toolBarHeight;
                            mTitleToolbar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                            mLastTitleHeight = toolBarHeight;
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. I'm just wondering whether I should put `mTitleContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)` afterwards, because I only needed to execute the code once.

Comment: That's sounds like a really good idea, since the listeners keeps on waiting for changes. :)